# Can anything be truer than true?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, ontology

The Wikipedia page of [Philosophy of Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_science) says, "This discipline overlaps with metaphysics, ontology, and epistemology, for example, when it explores the relationship between science and truth such as how Scientific Theory make falsifiable predictions which allow us to know they are truer than true." What does truer than true mean in this specific context? Also, what other possible meanings can "truer than true" otherwise have?

Comment: Ignore it.  It's a meaningless bit of wikipedia nonsense.

Comment: Definitely nonsense, as @mobileink says. Really, Wikipedia is a terrible source for philosophy (its strengths lie in other areas). If you want overviews of philosophical topics these are your best online sources: http://plato.stanford.edu/ and http://www.iep.utm.edu/.

Comment: Although I agree with @mobileink I do have a potential answer: There are truthes we hold, for instance, I can believe in something to be true and tell you I believe it and that is the "truth". Then there is the actual, unequivicable nature of reality itself, in the raw, pure "True" form. So Truth of reality is greater than truth of beliefs. That's just an example. I've heard it called big T truth vs little T truth.

Comment: The following part:
> ... such as how Scientific Theory make falsifiable predictions which allow us to know they are truer than true. has been removed again, ~two weeks after its injection into the article. Edit reason given: *"restore lead paragraph, removing possible vandalism"* I would suspect that even the person who put this "truer than true" part into the article didn't take it seriously. Wikipedia is most reliable about well-known, established and clear-cut information from the hard sciences (e.g. "molecular formula of Lysine"). It gets worse the more it gets into complex, highly specia

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Wikipedia vandalism which [has been removed](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Philosophy_of_science&type=revision&diff=724517020&oldid=723823900).